# Level shifts in an ARIMA model: fewer are better?

Tags: time-series

I've created an ARIMA (0 1 1)(0 1 2)12 model for our electricity costs. I have 44 months of monthly data, and have used X-12-ARIMA to do the model fitting. (I get similar results in R, it's just easier to use X-12-ARIMA and it gives a LOT of diagnostic output.) X-12-ARIMA allows you to enter a level shift easily, for example LS2008.Jul enters a level shift at July, 2008.

Unfortunately, between the utility and the state commission, rates get jerked around more often than I'd like. I know there were rate changes in July of 2008, September of 2009, May of 2010, and July of 2011. Is there any reason to not enter all four of these level shifts?

When I do the first and last (LS2008.Jul and LS2011.Jul, both close to the data boundaries), the results look good. When I insert the middle two (LS2009.Sep was a provisional jump up and LS2010.May a reversal), the ACF output shows issues. If it makes any difference, at the same time as LS2010.May, there were refunds in May-August that I've entered as USER (exogenous) variables.

Should this be? My analogous thinking is that a LS releases tension in a spline fit, as it were, and too many just supply too much slack. Even if I know that they are there.

Is there any reason to not include an LS when I know there should be one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Care should be taken because X12-ARIMA makes the mistake oF developing the ARIMA first anf THEN the empirically identified interventions. If your series is dominated by Level Shifts it might be prudent to identify them first using a null filter and then forming a suitable ARIMA structure after you have adjusted for the interventions. Additionally X12-ARIMA is potentially flawed because it doesn't identify local trends e.g. 0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5 ... or Seasonal Pulses. Local Time Trends are forms of intervention series which are often misdiagnosed as level shifts. You might want to post the actual data and your final model and find out what other more generalized approaches might yield. You can only learn by watching as Yogi once said !...he really said you can observe a lot by watching ...

Comment: Thanks! Two clarifications: 1) If the procedure is correct, I should always mark LS's that I know are there through domain knowledge, it's not a good thing to leave such information out if I know it independently. Correct? And 2) X-12-ARIMA's issue is with all outliers/interventions, including those marked by me, or is it only with outliers/interventions that X-12-ARIMA identifies automatically, through `outlier`?

Comment: I might add, I really like X-12-ARIMA for ARIMA work. It's slightly awkward to use with R, but the pages of diagnostic output that it gives are rather amazing... an education in itself, really. And there's the cachet of using the same software that governments around the world use. I look forward to X-13 which has been in beta for a while now. (Apparently unavailable to us mere mortals.)

Comment: Irrespective of your "ability to explain" the ls should be included because if you didn't include them the error process would be malformed. I don't follow your second comment. X12-ARIMA doesn't delete or augment the model , in other words no tests for necessity or sufficiency are incorporated. No tests are done for constancy of parameters or constancy of varaiance over time ; no tests are done on model errors to determine the optimal power transformation but for some reason transformations are selected on the original data which has no requiremrnts to be normally distributed.

Comment: In your answer, you say that "X12-ARIMA makes the mistake of developing the ARIMA first and THEN the empirically identified interventions". I'm interpreting "empirically identified" to mean identified by X12 in its automatic outlier detection procedure, as opposed to LS's that I know about a priori and manually enter. Just wanted to make sure I got that part right.

Comment: @wayne Yes you are right ! . I should have made that distinction. One other thing you are entering dates of LS that are known de jure. The true points of intervention may have started before or after thus the de facto dates may differ from the de jure dates. I ran into this when I studied the classic paper reflecting traffic deaths on texas highways as it reflected the date of a law change regarding seat belts.

Comment: Thanks! I had to submit my initial report a couple of days ago, and in the model I used I hadn't inserted the two additional LS's that I know of (for a total of four), because doing so caused the ACF of the residuals to show significance at lag 2, so I was skeptical. I'll add those two additional LS's and move forward investigating the ACF issue. (Four level shifts in 3.5 years, not counting little tweaks here and there, with a fifth LS about to hit us this month. That's our electricity provider...)

Comment: @Wayne If you can direct me how to do it we can go to a chat room for more detailed discussion. I have no clue as to how to do that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1405/discussion-between-irishstat-and-wayne)